# Why does my tic tac toe minimax algorithm not block certain diagonal moves?

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I've almost completed the logic for my tic tac toe minimax and its working quite well. But i'm still finding a few diagonal moves where the AI is seemingly getting it wrong. For example if you play square 3,6,5 and 7 you will win. It doesn't block the bottom corner for some reason.

Here's the minimax call recursively getting the best score that our computer can make:

```
          let compMove;
          let bestScore = -Infinity;
          for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (gameBoard.array[i] == '') {
              gameBoard.array[i] = 'X';
              let score = minimax(gameBoard.array, 0, true);
              gameBoard.array[i] = '';
              if (score > bestScore) {
                bestScore = score;
                compMove = i;
              }
            }
          }
```

Here is the actual minimax function itself:

```
          let scores = {
            X: 10,
            O: -10,
            tie: 0
          }
          
          const minimax = (board, depth, maximizingPlayer) => {
            let result = checkWinner(gameBoard.currentPlayer);
            
            if (result !== null) {
              return scores[result];
            }
            
            if (maximizingPlayer) {
              let bestScore = -Infinity;
              for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
              
                if (board[i] == '') {
                  board[i] = 'O';
                  let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, true);
                  board[i] = '';
                  if (score > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = score;
                  }
                }
              }
              return bestScore;

            } else {
                let bestScore = Infinity;
                for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                  if (board[i] == '') {
                    board[i] = 'X';
                    let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, false);
                    board[i] = '';
                    if (score < bestScore) {
                      bestScore = score;
                    }
                  }
                }
    
                return bestScore;
            }
          }
```

If anything sticks out to anyone I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm stumped!

If you'd like to test the current state of the game here's the codepen:

https://codepen.io/itswakana/pen/gOeMrym?editors=1111

Comment: Did you solved it? I tested the 3,5,6,7 plays and the computer played well i tested in this positions: https://prnt.sc/dxm5BIC_bgER and https://prnt.sc/L3JfSrZMF9cv and https://prnt.sc/yyFZjc4PJ1G0

Comment: Nah I haven't solved it yet, if you try 3,6,5,7 you'll see its not working. Sorry my listed order was slightly wrong.

Comment: You should not build the whole nifty user interface before you have a working engine. Trim down your code to the barebones engine, and debug it.

Comment: *" if you play square 3,6,5 and 7 you will win"* I must be confused because I remember tic tac toe required only 3 squares in a row to win. If those numbers are 0 index then it'd be (middle left), (bottom left), (middle right), and (bottom middle). That's not even 3 in a row. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these issues:

- As the "computer" plays with "O" the code where you set `compMove` should not move with "X", but move with "O". So the first code block you have in your post should be:

  ```
        let compMove;
        let bestScore = Infinity; // <-- to minimize (positive)
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
          if (gameBoard.array[i] == '') {
            gameBoard.array[i] = 'O'; // <-- not X
            let score = minimax(gameBoard.array, 0, true);
            gameBoard.array[i] = '';
            if (score < bestScore) { // <-- minimize
              bestScore = score;
              compMove = i;
            }
          }
        }
  ```
- `checkWinner(gameBoard.currentPlayer)` is always checking a win for the *same* player, as `gameBoard.currentPlayer` is not altered during the minimax search. So this will miss wins for the opponent. I would in fact leave `gameBoard.currentPlayer` alone, and pass an argument that is based on the `maximizingPlayer` argument:

  ```
  let result = checkWinner("XO"[+maximizingPlayer]); // dynamically determine player
  ```
- You always pass the current value of `maximizingPlayer` to the recursive call. When it is false, you pass false, and when it is true, you pass true. This means it never toggles (see next point).
- When *maximizing* the score, your code lets "O" make moves, but that is the minimizing player. So that needs to be switched.

  ```
       const minimax = (board, depth, maximizingPlayer) => {
          let result = checkWinner("XO"[+maximizingPlayer]); // <--

          if (result !== null) {
            return scores[result];
          }

          let bestMove;
          if (maximizingPlayer) {
            let bestScore = -Infinity;
            for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

              if (board[i] == '') {
                board[i] = 'X'; // <--
                let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, false); // <--
                board[i] = '';
                if (score > bestScore) {
                  bestMove = i;
                  bestScore = score;
                }
              }
            }
            return bestScore;

          } else {
              let bestScore = Infinity;
              for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (board[i] == '') {
                  board[i] = 'O'; // <--
                  let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, true); // <--
                  board[i] = '';
                  if (score < bestScore) {
                    bestMove = i;
                    bestScore = score;
                  }
                }
              }

              return bestScore;
          }
        }
  ```

With those changes it will work.

Final remark: it is a pity that in your code you have at least three concepts that correspond to the notion of "player": `maximizingPlayer` is a boolean, `Player` is an object with a `team` member, `currentPlayer` is a character property, and the `player` argument is the character too. This should be harmonised. Certainly the `currentPlayer` property serves hardly any purpose. It is just set here and there to a hard-coded "X" or "O" and then immediately passed as argument.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the in depth look into what was wrong, it seems i made quite a few mistakes. Could you explain to me what the argument inside checkWinner is doing on the code you wrote? I'm a little confused by it.

Comment: The expression translates the `maximizingPlayer` value to a "X" or "O". To achieve that, the value is first converted from boolean to integer, using the unary `+`. That value will be 0 or 1 and is used as an index to pick the correct character from the "XO" string.

Comment: That's clever, I never would have thought of it. I took some of your advice and reworked the different player properties to make the code a little cleaner to look at and understand. Thanks again.